# Docker complaining about $PATH when running from current directory

Tags: docker

When I see this error, I don't know what to do:

```
container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \".\": executable file not found in $PATH"
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \".\": executable file not found in $PATH".
```

It happens when I run:

```
docker run [IMAGE_NAME] .
```

How can I get this setup properly so I can run my docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is incorrect. You're trying to execute `.` when you should be trying to execute `[IMAGE_NAME]` like so:

```
docker run [IMAGE_NAME]
```

This should fix your issue.